# net-snmp flags in CMAKE

Tags: gcc, cmake, static-libraries, compiler-flags

Before anything, I just want to say I am very new to `CMAKE`, almost never used it but now forced to...

I am trying to include snmp features in a previous project, using `Net-SNMP` library. But first, I wrote a minimalistic code just to test my functions. According to the library tutorial, this is how I must compile the code:

First, I must create object file:

```
gcc -I. `net-snmp-config --cflags`   -c -o tfsnmpset.o tfsnmpset.c
```

Then, I must generate the executable:

```
gcc -o tfsnmpset tfsnmpset.o `net-snmp-config --libs`
```

By doing this, the program compiles perfectly and everything is fine. 
Now the project in which I want to incorporate that piece of code uses `CMakeLists.txt` to generate its makefile.

My question is, how do I include the following flags in my `CMakeLists.txt`?

```
When creating object files: `net-snmp-config --cflags` 
When generating executable: `net-snmp-config --libs`
```

I actually tried to build a library out of my code that uses `Net-SNMP` that I could just use in my main project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(snmp_daemon C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/gcc)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -I. `net-snmp-config --cflags`" )
add_library(tfsnmpset tfsnmp.c tfsnmp.h)
add_executable(snmp_daemon main.c ./tfsnmp.h)
target_link_libraries(snmp_daemon tfsnmpset)
```

The errors:

```
/media/user/xtra/apps/clion-2018.2.1/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/fabrice/projects/snmp-daemon/cmake-build-debug --target snmp_daemon -- -j 2
[ 25%] Linking C static library libtfsnmpset.a
[ 50%] Built target tfsnmpset
[ 75%] Linking C executable snmp_daemon
libtfsnmpset.a(tfsnmp.c.o): In function `tfsnmpset':
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:121: undefined reference to `snmp_parse_args'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:147: undefined reference to `snmp_get_do_debugging'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:147: undefined reference to `debugmsgtoken'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:147: undefined reference to `debugmsg'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:147: undefined reference to `debugmsgtoken'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:147: undefined reference to `debugmsg'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:194: undefined reference to `snmp_open'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:199: undefined reference to `snmp_sess_perror'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:207: undefined reference to `snmp_pdu_create'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:210: undefined reference to `snmp_parse_oid'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:211: undefined reference to `snmp_perror'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:214: undefined reference to `snmp_add_var'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:216: undefined reference to `snmp_perror'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:222: undefined reference to `snmp_close'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:230: undefined reference to `snmp_synch_response'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:236: undefined reference to `print_variable'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:239: undefined reference to `snmp_errstring'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:247: undefined reference to `fprint_objid'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:257: undefined reference to `snmp_sess_perror'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:262: undefined reference to `snmp_free_pdu'
/home/user/projects/snmp-daemon/tfsnmp.c:263: undefined reference to `snmp_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/snmp_daemon.dir/build.make:84: recipe for target 'snmp_daemon' failed
make[3]: *** [snmp_daemon] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/snmp_daemon.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/snmp_daemon.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/snmp_daemon.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/snmp_daemon.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'snmp_daemon' failed
make: *** [snmp_daemon] Error 2
```

Answer (score 4):

You should link to snmp libraries

```
find_library(NETSNMPAGENT "netsnmpagent")

find_library(NETSNMPMIBS "netsnmpmibs")

find_library(NETSNMP "netsnmp")

target_link_libraries(snmp_daemon tfsnmpset ${NETSNMPAGENT} ${NETSNMPMIBS} ${NETSNMP})
```